Help: Thevenin's and Norton's theorem
I am having trouble understanding the Thevenin's and the Norton's Theorems in more complex circuits, for example this task:
For the circuit shown in picture 4, calculate using Norton's or Thevenin's theorem
a) the apparent power of the voltage source
b) the apparent power of current source
c) the complex power of inductive reactance
given the values of R, X, C, I and E1

I do understand the concept of both theorems but am having trouble with creating the beginning schemes for this particular example where (by my professors' technique) you short circuit the voltage source and make a break in the circuit where the current source is after which you calculate impedance of that circuit and then with Kirchhoff's laws you get the current or in this example continue and calculate the power. So I am specifically having trouble with the scheme that would lead me to calculating impedance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Joanna, you've included figure 3. Why? The question and picture caption appears to only reference figure 4. Can we exclude looking at figure 3?

Joanna, I don't know what difficulties may be taking place in the area you live and that may be a distraction from your question. But it would help a little in getting some kind of response here if you would take a moment and add something to let us know you are still interested.

Figure 3 is irrelevant to this question I just couldn’t crop it out in the way that the values given for figure 4 would still be shown. I am still very much interested.

@Joanna Okay. I'll give it a shot. There are a number of ways to approach this. And I have to do some interpretation to guess at what you are studying, from the text you wrote. So I'll do what I can with that.

@Joanna Again, no response for a while. I'm sure there's a lot keeping you busy. But just a reminder.

Thank you a lot, I am currently working and am unable to check out everything with complete understanding so I will look into your approach by the end of the day, thank you for the help.

@Joanna It's been a few days. Any new thoughts/questions?


for this particular example where (by my professors' technique) you
short circuit the voltage source and make a break in the circuit where
the current source is after which you calculate impedance of that
circuit and then with Kirchhoff's laws you get the current or in this
example continue and calculate the power. So I am specifically having
trouble with the scheme that would lead me to calculating impedance.

This sounds like the superposition approach to me. It's not totally clear. But that's how it reads to me since you mention "short circuit the voltage source". So let's go with that approach:

The full schematic is on the left side. I've shorted the voltage source on the upper-right and opened the current source on the lower-right.
I've also indicated the final current directions on the full schematic (on left) and also the current directions I'll calculate for the right-side schematics. These are the currents that will be calculated and their directions. I've picked them, arbitrarily. You could randomize those, if you prefer. It really doesn't matter. What matters is that we are consistent about the work and how you combine them in the end. So pay attention as I go.
shorted voltage source schematic
We need to compute the the voltage drop across the left two components and then work out each current for the two devices. And then compute the voltage drop across the right two components and then work out each current for those two devices. Obviously, the sum in each case will equal the current source's value.
The left side voltage is \$V_{_\text{L}}=I\cdot\left(R\,\vert\vert\,-jX\right)=-j2\left(10\,\vert\vert\,-j10\right)=-10-j10\$. So we can work out the currents as \$I_{_\text{R}}=\frac{-10-j10}{10}=-1-j1\$ and \$I_{_\text{C}}=\frac{-10-j10}{-j10}=1-j1\$. These sum to \$-2j\$, as they should, given the current directions shown.
The right side voltage is \$V_{_\text{L}}=I\cdot\left(R\,\vert\vert\,jX\right)=-j2\left(10\,\vert\vert\,j10\right)=10-j10\$. So we can work out the currents as \$I_{_\text{R}}=\frac{10-j10}{10}=1-j1\$ and \$I_{_\text{L}}=\frac{10-j10}{j10}=-1-j1\$. These also sum to \$-2j\$, as they should, given the current directions shown.
opened current source schematic
The current on the left side branch will be \$\frac{j200}{10-j10}=-10+j10\$.
The current on the right side branch will be \$\frac{j200}{10+j10}=10+j10\$.
adding all these up for the left side schematic
The upper-right resistor's current will be the sum of the two currents found above. To be consistent, we have to subtract the left side branch current found in the opened current source case (since the direction is oppositely arranged) from the current found in the shorted voltage source case. So this current is \$9-j11\$.
The lower-right capacitor's current will be the sum of the two currents found above, too. To be consistent, we have to add the left side branch current found in the opened current source case (since the direction is arranged the same) to the current found in the shorted voltage source case. So this current is \$-9+j9\$.
The upper-left inductor's current will be the sum of the two currents found above. To be consistent, we have to add the right side branch current found in the opened current source case (since the direction is arranged the same) to the current found in the shorted voltage source case. So this current is \$9+j9\$.
The lower-left resistor's current will be the sum of the two currents found above. To be consistent, we have to subtract the right side branch current found in the opened current source case (since the direction is oppositely arranged) to the current found in the shorted voltage source case. So this current is \$-9-j11\$.
Finally, the current in the voltage source (pointed as indicated in the left side schematic) will be the inductor current minus the resistor current (one leaves the node and one enters the node, so the difference is what's important.) This will be \$9+j9-\left(9-j11\right)=j20\$.
The completed schematic is:

You should be able to answer any remaining questions.
